# Define datatype for Multidimensional Array

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

How do i declare the datatype for the below multidimensional array

```
settings = [

        “person" : [

            “name”:"bing",

            "status”:"done",

        ],

        “flags" : [

            “moved" :true

        ]

    ]
```

tried with `var settings = [String]()`, `var settings = [String[String:String]` but did not work

Comment: this is a dictionary, not an array.

Answer (score 1):

After correcting all the small mistakes (you're using `“` instead of `"`)

```
let settings = ["person": ["name": "bing", "status": "done"], "flags": ["moved": true]]
```

Alt clicking settings is showing:

```
let settings: [String : Dictionary<String, NSObject>]
```

But you could also declare it as `[String: [String: AnyObject]]`